# Jquery modal popup display only once per user session

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that displays a modal popup when the page loads. Is there a way so it only displays once per user session. I have rad many posts but for whatever reason I can't get them to work in my script.

my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).load(function(){
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();
    });

});
```

The modal popup is made up of:

```
<div id="dialog1" title="IMPORTANT!">
    <div class="imaindateselleft_padding_right_red">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Mant thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: dialog() is not a function, according to console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to integrate with cookie. Let it display the dialog and store the value that the dialog has been shown in the cookie so it won't be displayed next time.

And in this approach, I am using [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). (Feel free to use vanilla javascript to r/w cookies). And I also assume you use jQuery UI to call `dialog`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dialogShown = $.cookie('dialogShown');

    // On newer versions of js-cookie, API use:
    // var dialogShown = Cookies.get('dialogShown');

    if (!dialogShown) {
        $(window).load(function(){
            $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();
            $.cookie('dialogShown', 1);
            // On newer versions of js-cookie, API use:
            // Cookies.set('dialogShown', 1);

        });
    }
    else {
        $("#dialog1").hide();
    }
});
```

What the code above does, is simply to set the cookie once the dialog has been popped before. The only way to let the same user to see the dialog again is when the [cookie expires](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#user-content-expires) (which you can set), or the user clears the cookies.

**Edit**: Second way to achieve this, you can use your localStorage if the browser supports it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dialogShown = localStorage.getItem('dialogShown')

    if (!dialogShown) {
        $(window).load(function(){
            $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();
            localStorage.setItem('dialogShown', 1)
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#dialog1").hide();
    }


});
```

Comment: hi, I have tried your code but the modal popup does not load, the div is just displays at the top of the page. But thanks for trying.

Comment: @DCJones Is it writing the value to cookies? Can you try my second approach?

Comment: Hi again, That sort of works. But when the pages is loaded for a second time the DIV appears at the top of the page.

Comment: Do you not hide the dialog on the page loads? Can you try my second approach now?

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for your time. My knowledge has increased, thank you.

Comment: 2nd option works properly. Didn't used jquery cookie. Just want to do it using localStorage. Thanks this saved me a lot of time