# Modal show once per session

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have modal wizard that shows an instruction in my page. I want to show the modal once per session

Here's my code

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="wizardmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Property</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- Smart Wizard HTML -->
          <div id="smartwizard">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#step-1">Step 1<br /><small>Add Property</small></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#step-2">Step 2<br /><small>Type of Property</small></a></li>
              </ul>

              <div>




        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

I'm currently using modal show.

```
 $(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#wizardmodal').modal('show');
    });
```

The modal automatically show when i reload the page. What should I do?

Comment: use the session variable to check whether the session has started or not.

Answer (score 8):

Use [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to track whether it's been shown to the user in that session.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-modal')){
    $('#wizardmodal').modal('show');
    sessionStorage.setItem('shown-modal', 'true');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693780/7035903)

You can use jQuery Cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dialogShown = $.cookie('dialogShown');

if (!dialogShown) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#wizardmodal').modal('show');
        $.cookie('dialogShown', 1);
    });
}
});
```

Or Browser's localStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dialogShown = localStorage.getItem('dialogShown')

if (!dialogShown) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#wizardmodal').modal('show');
        localStorage.setItem('dialogShown', 1)
    });
}
});
```